# Write a String value (10 chars) with the Modbus protocol to tag 400001

Tags: java, modbus

I have the following case: I need to send information to the tags 400001 through 400006 that will displayed on a PTV screen. I do not have much experience using modbus, but from what I understand is that I should use Function code 16 to set the tag value.

I currently have the following code and that seems to work in a simulator:

```
// Open the connection
TCPMasterConnection connection = new TCPMasterConnection(address);
connection.setPort(Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT);
connection.connect();

ModbusTCPTransaction trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(connection); //the transaction

// Prepare the request
SimpleRegister[] registers = new SimpleRegister[1];
registers[0] = new SimpleRegister(15);

WriteMultipleRegistersRequest req = new WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(400001, registers);

req.setUnitID(1);
trans.setRequest(req);
//No we are ready for action. The last part is executing the prepared transaction the given (repeat) number of times and then for cleanup, close the connection:
log.debug("ModbusSlave: FC" + req.getFunctionCode() + " ref=" + req.getReference() + " value=" + registers[0].getValue());
trans.execute();

// Close the connection
connection.close();
```

But how to set a string like "0010323"?